# border to input on entering and leaving focus when it has a valid value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a couple of inputs which I store their information in an object, I am trying to click on the input to make me focus and if it is empty or if its length is greater than or equal to 0, it paints a red border, if I write something this border is removed, even if the value of the input is at 0 and I exit the input, this border is removed, only show it when it has the focus and its value is less than or equal to 0, I have a function that does this, but I have several inputs and if I use it in another when I click on one it marks the other, how can I do this in different inputs?

> inputs

```
        <div class="superficie info" :class="{'input-error' : validInput}">
             <label>area</label>
             <input type="number" v-model="objInfo.area" @focus="inputFocus" @blur="inputBlur" @input="validandoInput">
        </div>
    
        <div class="address info" :class="{'input-error' : validInput}">
            <label>address</label>
            <input type="text" :value="objInfo.address" @focus="inputFocus" @blur="inputBlur" @input="validandoInput">
        </div>
```

> functions

```
const validInput= ref(false)
const inputFocus = (e) => {
    if(objInfo.value.area === ''){
        validInput.value = true
    }  
}

const inputBlur = (e) => {
    validInput.value = false
}

const validandoInput = () => {
    if(objInfo.value.area === ''){
        validInput.value = true
        return
    }
    validInput.value = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> when I click on one it marks the other, how can I do this in different inputs

It is actually not marking the other, it is most likely marking them both at the same time, since you are using a single variable `validInput` to track validity of all the input fields, meaning if any of them fails, all of them will have the `input-error` class. The reason it might look like it is painting only the other one is because the focus border of the active one might mask your custom error style.

I am basing this on my experience with trying to recreate the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-architecture-k4hduk?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

A solution could be to introduce separate variables to track validation state of each input field separately, perhaps something like this:

```
const inputValidity = ref({
  areaInput: false,
  adressInput: false,
})
```

Then you can target these properties for example like this:

```
<template>
  <input @input="validateAreaInput" />
</template>

<script>
...

const validateAreaInput = (input) => {
  if (input) {
    inputValidity.value.areaInput = true;
  }
  inputValidity.value.areaInput = false;
}
</script>
```

You can take this a lot further by defining validator functions for certain cases and assigning them to data properties, and then use a generic validator function where you only pass in the input and a field name. This is a rudimentary solution which doesn't scale well, but i think will help to get off the ground. There are existing libraries to solve this kind of problem here are two of them for your consideration:

https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/

https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/